# Fetch data periodically from server and re-render view in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I want to fetch data from server periodically and refresh rows when data is fetched by `setState()` but the rows doesn't re-render after `setState()`.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    rows: []
  }

  this.refreshList = this.refreshList.bind(this);
}

refreshList() {
  req.get('/data').end(function (error, res) {
    // type of res is array of objects
    this.setState({
      rows: res
    });
  });
}

// call this method on button clicked
handleClick() {
  this.refreshList();
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Refresh List</button>
      <Table rows={this.state.rows}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when call `refreshList()` new feteched data doesn't render.

My table component is:

```
// Table component
export class Table extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rows: props.rows
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.rows.map((row, i) => (
        <div>{row.title}</div>
      ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help. How can I refresh list on click button?

Comment: where do you call `refreshList`? what kind of object is returned? what was the initial value of the `state`? show some code.

Comment: I edited codes. Thanks.

Comment: I don&#39;t see you binding `handleClick()`. Do you get any error or warning?

Comment: Ok, now I see the button, and the method is correctly bound. What about the response you receive from your JSON request, are you sure the data is at root level, maybe you need to `setState({ rows: res.data })` instead? On a side-note, you should make your Table component stateless, and just use props to populate your data.

Comment: @jaxx thanks a lot. with stateless Table component, list will be refresh.

Comment: Oh so updating props in the child component didn't update the corresponding state? That's interesting. Perhaps it would've worked with a `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle function, but regardless, simpler is better, there's no point in replicating props into state if you're not going to make use of state in the child component. Glad it's working now.

Comment: thanks so much @jaxx :) `componentWillReceiveProps` solves my problem too.

Comment: @Hossein actually I think I understand what was going on. The constructor was only called when the Table component was initially mounted. When you passed new props after a refresh, the new props weren't being used (constructor is not called again), so your state remained unaffected. So either setting the state through `componentWillReceiveProps` or turning Table into a stateless component and using props directly (the better solution imo) both work, makes sense. And you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table component never changes its state after the construction. You can fix it easily by updating the state from new props:

```
export class Table extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rows: props.rows
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    this.setState({
      rows: newProps.rows
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.rows.map((row, i) => (
        <div>{row.title}</div>
      ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However, if your table component is so simple, you can make it stateless and use `props` directly without `setState()`:

```
export class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.props.rows.map((row, i) => (
        <div>{row.title}</div>
      ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note there is no need for `constructor` now. We could actually make it a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrow function:

```
req.get('/data').end((error, res)=> {
  // type of res is array of objects
  this.setState({
    rows: res
  });
});
```

With the ES5 style callback function, the context of `this` gets lost.

You could also bind `this` directly to a local variable, i.e., `var that = this` and stick with the `function` syntax, but I think most would agree what the ES6 arrow syntax is nicer.

Comment: Would need more information then:

- Are you sure that the res data is arriving as you expect?

- Do you see it successfully getting set in the component's state?

- What does the render function look like?

Comment: yes, data fetched successfully from server. `this.state.rows` is array. I think we can't override objects in states by `setState()`, we can change only items in array by `setState()`.

Comment: Nope, you can certainly replace entire arrays with `setState`. Post your `render()` method please.

Comment: @Hossein you can override object. please add render part of your component too